# Не работает функция MoveFile (WinAPI)

Tags: c, winapi

Недавно начал изучать c++. Не могу понять в чём ошибка. Не перемещается файл.
Вот код:

```
char WinDir[256];
GetWindowsDirectory(WinDir, 256);
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];`введите сюда код`
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);

MoveFile(path, WinDir);
```

Comment: А код возврата и код ошибки через GetLastError кто смотреть будет? Но есть у меня подозрение, что из процесса нельзя свой же файл переместить...

Comment: Я думаю у вас защита от записи в Windows Директорию. Вызоваете функцию GetLastError для получения кода ошибки.

Comment: GetLastError выдал 5. Значит и вправду защита от записи.Спасибо:)